# Keras: Why the output size of a Conv2D layer doesn't match the expected shape of feature map?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am trying to run a convolutional neural network on MNIST images (28x28 gray-scale images) as inputs. To do it, I am using Keras (code is shown below). What I am having trouble understanding is why the shape of the convolutional layers doesn't match the shape I would expect them to have.

Particularizing to the first convolutional layer, what I am trying to use are 32 feature maps, convolving all of them with 3x3 kernels. The batch-size I am using is 200.

Given this I would expect that the shape of of the first Conv2D layer was **(200, 26, 26, 32)** i.e. 200 samples processed (due to batch size), 32 feature maps whose size was **26x26** (due to the convolution applied to the 28x28 input images with a 3x3 kernel).

However, the size I am getting by using `model.summary()` is **(200, 9, 9, 32)** as shown below:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (200, 9, 9, 32)           320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (200, 4, 4, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (200, 4, 4, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (200, 512)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (200, 256)                131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (200, 10)                 2570      
=================================================================
Total params: 134,218
Trainable params: 134,218
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The code I am using is:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
# MNIST
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],28,28,1).astype('float32')
X_test  = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],28,28,1).astype('float32')

X_train = X_train/255
X_test  = X_test/255

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), epochs = 10, batch_size = 200, verbose = 2)

model.summary()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact that `Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)` is a convolution layer with 32 features maps in output, a kernel size of 3x3 and **a stride of 3**.

What you meant is probably `Convolution2D(32, (3, 3))` or simply `Convolution2D(32, 3)`.